# How do you check a field in a query for specific values if and only if another field had a specific value?

Tags: date, ms-access, expression

I want to write an expression in my Access query to check to see if an item we are running *next week* has run in the *4 weeks* before that date. I'm having trouble understanding how you can check something in the same query and then use the returned value of that check to check a few more things. The method I've tried is to write make another query that will use the results of the first query (where items from `7/20/2015` are isolated) to check the dates of those items, but I run into a problem because then I have to tie back that query to the original table, which duplicates the data.

Written in pseudo-code, it would look somewhat like the following:

If the `item` has a `job_date` of `7/20/2015`, check all instances of that item prior to `7/20/2015` and if there is no instance for weeks `7/13/2015`, `7/6/2015`, `6/29/2015`, or `6/22/2015`, then return the `item`.

Written in a more visual way:

```
item          job_date
A             6/22/2015
A             6/29/2015
A             7/6/2015
A             7/13/2015
A             7/20/2015

item          job_date
B             6/15/2015
B             
B             
B             
B             
B             7/20/2015

item          job_date
C             6/22/2015
C             
C             
C             7/13/2015
C             7/13/2015
C             7/20/2015

item          job_date
D             
D             
D             
D             
D             
D
```

Item A would not be returned because we have been running continuously. Item B would return because even though we ran it on `6/15/2015`, that was more than 4 weeks before `7/20/2015`. `Item D` would not return because it doesn't have a row with the target date (`7/20/2015`).

**Notes:**

- Ideally, I will use expressions that will always determine next week's date automatically, I just used hard dates here for clarity. If you want to use the hard dates as well please feel free.
- Our weeks begin on Mondays.
- An item can run multiple times in one week. For example, `Item C` can have 2 rows with `7/13/2015` and `7/13/2015`. The job number (not shown, but exists in the same table) is the unique identifier in the table. If `Item C` were to run twice, then the jobs would be `H000001584-0030` and `H00001584A-0030`.

Comment: If the *7/20/2015 job_date* for item *B* was not there, would *B* be included in the query result set (when the target date is *7/20/2015*)?

Comment: No. This is because we are only considering items with a row that has the target date. Then that list of items will have their previous weeks checked.

Comment: Will *job_date* always be either Null or a Monday date?

Comment: Yes, always one of the two.

Comment: 99% of the time it is a Monday. The rest of the time it is a Null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query below returns this result set from your sample data when I supply *7/20/2015* as the parameter value:

```
item
----
B
```

The query includes a subquery which returns those items which have rows with *job_date* values in the 28 days before the target date.  Note the subquery does not return an *item* which had no *job_date* values in that range --- so it gives you only those items which did have a *job_date* in that range.  Therefore left joining to the subquery and asking for only rows where the "right side" is Null means that we exclude those items from the final result set.

```sql
PARAMETERS pTarget DateTime;
SELECT j.item
FROM
    dbo_job AS j
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT [item]
        FROM dbo_job
        WHERE job_date>=DateAdd('d', -28, [pTarget]) And job_date<[pTarget]
        GROUP BY [item]
    ) AS sub
    ON j.item = sub.item
WHERE j.job_date=[pTarget] AND sub.item Is Null
GROUP BY j.item;
```

Comment: Nice, except that _in the four weeks before_ may not mean exactly 28 days so you could have to use `DateDiff("ww", date1, date2, 2, 2)`.

Comment: I pasted in your query and I'm getting the error "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'item' as part of an aggregate function." All I did was paste and adjust the SELECT statement and put in the pTarget. `PARAMETERS pTarget DateTime;
SELECT dbo_job.item
FROM
    dbo_job AS j
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT [item]
        FROM dbo_job
        WHERE job_date>=DateAdd('d', -28, #7/20/2015#) And job_date<#7/20/2015#
        GROUP BY item
    ) AS sub
    ON j.item = sub.item
WHERE j.job_date=#7/20/2015# AND sub.item Is Null
GROUP BY j.item;`

Comment: Here: `SELECT dbo_job.item FROM dbo_job AS j`  Since `dbo_job` is aliased `AS j`, you can't ask for `dbo_job.item`  Instead either use `SELECT j.item` as I had it or drop the alias.  Note if you drop the alias, you'll need to change all the other `j.` references.

Comment: Ok. The query output a list of items successfully. I'm manually checking them now to see if they are correct.